# How to set minimum DatePicker date to current date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to set the minimum date the user can choose in a DatePicker to the current date. I've tried this:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.event_date);
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

That gives me the following exception:

```
12-01 12:23:31.226: E/AndroidRuntime(10311): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Sat Dec 01 12:23:31 EST 2012 does not precede toDate: Sat Dec 01 12:23:31 EST 2012
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The error says you cannot set the minimum date to *exactly* now. Try subtracting a second:

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

---

From the source code the minimum date must be before, not equal to, the current date:

```
if (date.before(mMinDate)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromDate: " + mMinDate.getTime()
            + " does not precede toDate: " + date.getTime());
}
```

So you simply need to subtract enough time from now (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) pass `date.before(mMinDate)`.

Comment: apart from above solution, you can simply set the minimum values for that particular date as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23006624/1288725)

Comment: This solution partially works for me on 5.0.1 (Samsung S4) with `DatePickerDialog`. I can **still** select any date in the current month. However, I can't select a date from a previous month.

Comment: Can also use: setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

Comment: @ShubhamA Did you solve this issue because it happened with me too.
I can select any date in the current month.

Comment: **- 1000** doesn't work for Kotlin for some cases :(

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use a custom dialog. Use this single line code:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: This doesn't work for devices below 5.0 for some reason. The marked answer works for all the cases.

Comment: This will result in the same exception as the OP described (at least on Android API 16 and 18) and it's just a different way to select the date picker.

Answer (score 8):

Check the Android *DatePickerDialog* set *minimum* and *maximum date* code.

Here is the [examples](http://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-datepickerdialog-in-android.html).

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,year, month, day);  

    //Get the DatePicker instance from DatePickerDialog  
    DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();  
    //Set the DatePicker minimum date selection to current date  
    dp.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());//get the current day  
    //dp.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);// Alternate way to get the current day  

    //Add 6 days with current date  
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,6);  

    //Set the maximum date to select from DatePickerDialog  
    dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());  
    //Now DatePickerDialog have 7 days range to get selection any one from those dates
```

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers

Answer (score 8):

This worked perfectly for me. easy and nice.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this,
              Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,
                Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this line to your DatePicker Fragment will set the minimum date as current date & disable the previous months.

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 3):

For custom date

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2017, 0, 1);//Year,Month -1,Day
your_date_picker.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

The minimum date can't be the instant moment

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);

timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(min);
```

Comment: I don't want to set the default date I want to set the minimum date the user can choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
datePicker.setMinDate(new GregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: some comment would help this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

OR

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this,
          Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,
            Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the current date **In Kotlin** do it this way:

```
myDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis())
```