# setMinDate() for DatePicker doesn't work

Tags: android, datepicker

```
DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
datepicker.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

It just doesn't work. It works only in the xml (`android:minDate="mm/dd/yyyy"`), but I need to set the minimum date dynamically to the current day.
My minimum API is 11.

Comment: Doesn't work? Does that mean it crashes? It silently fails (are you using `try/catch`?)? Or what?

Comment: No. It just don't limit the options.

Comment: Uhm its strange behaviour, it should works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date It seems that you could try subtracting a second before you set the date?

Comment: @span I remember that thread also, but in that situation it was crashing (not just refusing to work).

Comment: I saw that thread. In my case, it doesn't crash. Maybe because it in a custom dialog?

Comment: What if you set it to a date in a different year (Use `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5)`)? I have a hunch there is a bug in `setMinDate()` (from looking at the source code).

Comment: `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`   `cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);`       `datepicker.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

***P.S: Solution used to work before but might be outdated now.***

Try something like this. If I understand correctly, you wish to set the minimum date of spinner to today's date. It works for me without giving any error:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
    long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    datepicker.setMinDate(time);
```

In your xml I am supposing that you have something like this:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: The problem isn't errors. Actually, it just doesn't work. Yours code too =\

Comment: This solution does not work, you can still pick the greyed out dates.

Comment: @PeterFile : have you get any solution for it ?