# Datepicker gives time not between exception

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using a datepicker and want to set the min date to today and the max date to today one year ahead.

I do this like:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

When I don't do - 1000 then I get another exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Sat Apr 11 23:59:59 CEST 2015 does not precede toDate: Sat Apr 11 08:24:19 CEST 2015
```

thats because the date may not be equal to today. So I extract 1000 ms.

I don't know how to solve the new exception. I tried to count + 1000 ms on the maxDate but that didn't solve it.

EDIT:

I create my cal like this:

```
 cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

I just set the start date to the minimum and the end date to the maximum off that day.

Comment: that's solve my problem but what if i want to maintain the time too do i need to create another instance of calendar and manage both separately ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `MinDate` is higher than `MaxDate`. As per the exception.

Comment: Yes I know that but I don't know how to fix this. Whatever I try it always fails.

Comment: your minDate is in 2015 rather than 2014. use 'cal.getTimeInMillis()' for setMinDate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: @user1007522 How do you creating your Calendar?

Comment: I don't see the problem? You asked for how I created the Calendar and I edited my post to show you. I forgot to add it in the first place. I don't want to paste code in my comments thats why I did this.

Comment: @user1007522 I see it. My solution is similar to yours, but it shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) it is indeed shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your solutions. I got a similar problem in one of my android apps. Also I want to limit the datepicker calendar range to show a minimum date 100 years ago and a maximum date of 5 years ago. Based on the codes that you shared, the following is my solution:

```
Calendar calmin = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calmax = Calendar.getInstance();              

calmin.add(Calendar.YEAR, -100);
calmin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calmin .getMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calmin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calmin .getMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
calmin.set(Calendar.SECOND, calmin .getMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
calmin.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calmin.getMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

calmax.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
calmax.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calmax.getMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calmax.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calmax.getMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE));
calmax.set(Calendar.SECOND, calmax.getMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));
calmax.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calmax.getMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = null;
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ageGateActivity.this, 
    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, dateSetListener, year, 
    month, day);
       
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calmin.getTimeInMillis());          
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calmax.getTimeInMillis());
```