# Android DatePickerDialog Api 23 (Android 6)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am triggering a DatePickerDialog, It's working and showing fine till api 22 (Android 5.1), I am setting mix and max dates on it (min = current date, max = 1 month starting from current date), but It's just showing current date in Api 23, I attached code and images.

```
///////////////////////////////datepickerdialog///////////////////////////////
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        /*
            Create a DatePickerDialog using Theme.

                DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener,
                    int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
         */

        // DatePickerDialog THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22){

            dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
            dpd.getDatePicker().getCalendarView().setShowWeekNumber(false);

        }

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        long mindate = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        long maxdate = calendar.getTime().getTime();

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mindate);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxdate);

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mindate);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){

            dpd.setTitle("");

        }

        // Return the DatePickerDialog
        return  dpd;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        // Do something with the chosen date

        month++;

        evento_fecha = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;          


        month--;

        datetime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        datetime.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        datetime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        fecha = mSDF.format(datetime.getTime());

        //fecha_seleccionada.setText(dia+"/"+mes+"/"+year);
        fecha_seleccionada.setText(fecha);

    }
}
```

[image: Android 5.1]

[image: Android 6]

ANSWER 1: Results[image: ANSWER 1: Results]

Comment: Ok, I am testing on a Samsung Android 4.1 and I got errors, see image above (in the question)

Comment: which code are you using ??

Comment: Error is in this lines: long mindate = System.currentTimeMillis(); dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mindate);

Comment: I'm using your lines for setting min and max dates

Comment: see my update answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll put those lines into a single line

Comment: did you get it or not ??

Comment: I'm going to sleep right now, it's almost 3am in my country, I'll try it later and let you know, thank you

Comment: Buddy, I'm still getting the same error in this line: dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: I edited my code, I forgot a few lines. That's my original code to set min a max dates

Comment: Does this issue have to do with the theme I am using?, maybe

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this style in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_sheet</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>     

</style>
```

The textColorPrimary property was showing all days numbers in white, I used this property in order to set the action bar text to white. I was wrong because I had to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for this purpose, so I changed my theme style to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_sheet</item>

    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>     

</style>
```

and the result was as expected.

Answer (score 3):

DatePicker / DatePickerDialog not appearing properly on Android Marshmallow / API 23 is a theme issue. I suggest, instead of using default theme or writing custom styles, instantiate the **DatePickerDialog** using '**theme**' option:

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

API 23 onwards, Material theme should be used for the dialog. Use `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert` for the theme parameter.

For **Xamarin** Android - use `Android.Resource.Style.ThemeMaterialLightDialogAlert`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DatePicker` you have set `MinDate` to `currentTimeMillis()` and in your `MaxDate` you have add `1 MONTH` to your `Calendar`.

Just simple use this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_totalStone);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                                c.set(year, month, day);
                                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
                                textView.setText(date);

                                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

                Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
                d.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);

                dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(d.getTimeInMillis());
                dpd.show();


            }

        });

    }
```

In my DatePicker I have Date `June 25` and it select and as your requirement you have `MaxDate` 1 Month it's show in ScreenShot.

**ScreenShot : 1**

[image]

**ScreenShot : 2**

[image]

**Update :**

Replace your this code

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        long mindate = calendar.getTime().getTime();

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mindate);
```

with this

```
  dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: I tested my code (the one in the question) on a Android Emulator and it's working fine, the calendar looks like yours but on real devices. (the pics I attached above belong to a Motorola g3 phone)

Comment: It's a theme issue, days of the week are showing white instead of black (allowed) and grey(not allowed)

Comment: Imagine that in your example, all days numbers are white but current date

Comment: @user4216713 because it is selected `Date` that's why it's color is `White`.

Comment: It was a good answer but my code was ok, like I said, it was an issue (Api 23) related to the app theme.