# Android IllegalArgumentException for Date picker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

The date picker I used for my activity crashed on KitKat but works on every other newer operating systems. This is the exception I get on old devices:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Mon Apr 10 07:59:25 EDT
>   2017 does not precede toDate: Mon Apr 10 07:59:25 EDT 2017

**Code block stack trace is pointing at:**

```
private void showDatePicker(){
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
   getActivity(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   //this is where the crash happens
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
   datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Please let me know if the information regarding the question is sufficient. Any fix for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set minimum DatePicker date to current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this issue applying a delay:

```
private void showDatePicker(){
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
   getActivity(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   //this is where the crash happens
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 10000);
   datePickerDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: Any reason why it's happening? Also will this affect the behaviour on newer devices/OSs?

Comment: In my app this fix did not affect on the new devices/OS`s. I think this happens because the Android cannot set a min date that is the same as the current date.

Comment: @Dinuka it happens due to a bug in CalendarView for pre-API21, and for calendarViewMode == MODE_HOLO for API21. For newer versions of SDK the code of CalendarView is different and doesn't contain the issue

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue create a timestamp for minDate just before instantiation of DatePickerDialog:

```java
private void showDatePicker(){
   long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
      getActivity(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(now);
   datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

---

This crash happens due to a bug in CalendarView for pre-API21, and for `calendarViewMode == MODE_HOLO` for API21.

Although `setMinDate` contains a correction highlighted with a comment:

```java
public void setMinDate(long minDate) {
    ...
    mMinDate.setTimeInMillis(minDate);
    // make sure the current date is not earlier than
    // the new min date since the latter is used for
    // calculating the indices in the adapter thus
    // avoiding out of bounds error
    Calendar date = mAdapter.mSelectedDate;
    if (date.before(mMinDate)) {
        mAdapter.setSelectedDay(mMinDate);
    }
    // reinitialize the adapter since its range depends on min date
    mAdapter.init();
```

The check in `setSelectedDay` compares `mMinDate` and `mSelectedDate` only with date accuracy:

```java
public void setSelectedDay(Calendar selectedDay) {
    if (selectedDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == mSelectedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
            && selectedDay.get(Calendar.YEAR) == mSelectedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        return;
    }
```

`mSelectedDate` and `mMinDate` are points into the same day, so that `mSelectedDate` will remain unchanged (i.e. in a wrong state `mSelectedDate < mMinDate`).

Then the control flow will run up to `mAdapter.init`, and then into `getWeeksSinceMinDate`. In this function a comparison of `mMinDate` and `mSelectedDate` will be performed with millisecond accuracy:

```java
private int getWeeksSinceMinDate(Calendar date) {
    if (date.before(mMinDate)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromDate: " + mMinDate.getTime()
                + " does not precede toDate: " + date.getTime());
    }
```

And because `mSelectedDate` was initialized in few milliseconds before `mMinDate` the crash will occur.

In a newer implementation this code was rewritten, so this issue is missing for API21+.